# Copy and paste a table from one word document to another SAS DDE

Tags: ms-word, sas, dde

I'm using SAS v9.4, running a connection via DDE to Word 2010.

I would like to copy and paste an entire table from onw word document to another. The table is bookmarked "IDX" and I am able to select the table using the following code:

```
options noxsync noxwait xmin;
filename sas2word dde 'winword|system';
data _null_;
  file sas2word;
  put '[EditGoTo.Destination = "IDX"]';
  put '[TableSelectTable]';
run;
```

I have tried `put '[ctrl+c]';`, `put '[copy]';`, `put '[TableCopy]';`, `put '[SelectionCopy]';` but nothing seems to work, and the code crashes. Does anyone know the syntax to copy the entire table, then paste it into a different document?

Comment: Try `Copy`, capital C and `Paste` with capital P. Those have been around for a long time, it's hard to imagine they're different. Have you checked the Excel reference for what it was then?

Comment: Also, if you're working with multiple files you may want to have specific filerefs for each, or it will be hard to know which is going where.

Comment: Unfortunately `Copy` and `Paste` don't work, they just crash in the same way :( I like the idea about different filerefs, once I get copy/paste to work within one document I'll definitely try and implement that. I found an Excel reference to `copy()` here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/DDE-simple-copy-amp-paste-existing-values/td-p/225528, but that also crashes so I'm not sure what is going wrong

Comment: Do you have the parenthesis included in the command?

Comment: I've tried with and without the parenthasis, neither work :(

Comment: Try copy("IDX") is the only other command I can think of at the moment. In the Excel docs it's still a COPY() command as well.

Comment: What is the ODS destination that is creating the document ? `ods rtf` ? `ods word` ?

Comment: Describe the crash. Are there log messages ? What are they ? Does SAS freeze up ? Does Word freeze up ? Does SAS crash to desktop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is SAS 9.4M4 sample code that use experimental `ODS WORD` destination to create two Word documents, and copies a table from one to the other. YMMV, and you probably have addition work regarding issues such a table wrapping and anchoring.

```
filename one "c:\temp\one.docx";
filename two "c:\temp\two.docx";

ods _all_ close;

title; footnote;

options nocenter nonumber nodate;

ods word file=one;
  proc print data=sashelp.class (obs=5);
  proc print data=sashelp.cars (obs=5);
  proc print data=sashelp.demographics (obs=5);
  proc print data=sashelp.class (obs=5);
  run;
ods word close;

ods word file=two;
  proc print data=sashelp.cars (obs=10);
  run;
ods word close;

* start WORD;
options noxsync noxwait xmin;
%sysexec start "Yada yada yada" winword;
%let rc = %sysfunc(sleep(5,1));
%put NOTE: &=rc;

* define channel for sending commands;
filename word_cmd dde 'winword|system';

* put will send the commands to WORD;
data _null_;
  file word_cmd;
  cmd = cats ( "[FileOpen.Name=", quote(trim(pathname("One"))), "]");
  put cmd;

  put '[EditBookmark name:="IDX3", goto:=1]';
  put '[NextObject]';
  put '[GoToNextSection]';
  put '[TableSelectTable]';
  put '[EditCopy]';

  cmd = cats ( "[FileOpen.Name=", quote(trim(pathname("Two"))), "]");
  put cmd;
  put '[Selection.Goto(wdGotoLine, wdGotoLast)]';
  put '[EditPaste]';
run;
```

The Word command `ListCommands` will create a document containing a table of all the Word Commands and active key mappings.

```
data _null_;
  file word_cmd;
  put '[ListCommands]';
run;
```

The list goes on for 10 pages in Word 2016.  Word commands are also invokable from dde connections.  Unfortunately `ListCommands` lists a descriptive command name, and not the command that dde actually requires, and does not actually list all commands.  The WordMVP site (https://wordmvp.com) has assembled a list - ["Word for Windows commands"](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/CommandsList.htm)

> Word has a built-in command ListCommands, which produces a table of all the Word commands with their current key and menu assignments. However, it does not list the commands using their actual names; nor does it include descriptions of what the commands actually do.
>   …
>   [WordCmndsPDF.zip](https://wordmvp.com/Downloads/WordCmndsPDF.Zip) contains a list of all interceptable Word commands (Word 97 and above), using their correct English names

Another reference for Word commands can be found at ["Visual Basic Equivalents for WordBasic Commands"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa158432(v=office.10)), 6/13/2014.

A SAS conference paper search for "WORD DDE" will also provide additional material.

Comment: DDE will never die. (?)